# Keeping the same /home partition after a clean install

Tags: partitioning, mount, home-directory

I currently have 2 partitions for my ubuntu installation:  A `/` partition and a `/home` partition.

When Ubuntu 13.04 is released I plan to reinstall ubuntu while keeping the same home partition.  Is it safe to just mount the `/home` partition directly in the partitioning process of the installation? Because there are files present in my home partition already will the installer wipe the partition or will it just mount the partition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is  safe for the most part as long as you don't click the format check box. I've installed Ubuntu myself in this way for three releases now, and have not lost any data. However most would encourage you to backup before attempting this.

When the partitioning window shows up while installing Ubuntu click the format box on the `/`

[image]

But do not format  `/home`

[image]