# Can I reuse other OS /home directory for Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem

I currently have Mint 14 set up on a 128GB SSD, with my /home directory on a 1TB Hard Disk.
I am thinking about installing Ubuntu 14.04 when it comes out.

I understand that I can select a different home partition during installation and not format it.

Will the home directory just work, considering it is a change of distro or are there any Ubuntu specific contents in the /home directory that need to be created?

lsblk output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 103.3G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /home
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsblk` to your question? This will show us what your current partitions look like. If you have your home directory on a seperate partition you should be able to designate that as the home directory in a new install as long as you do NOT format /home: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285212/keeping-the-same-home-partition-after-a-clean-install

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. output duly added.
Do you think there are any issues going from Linux Mint to Ubuntu?

Comment: Those that say it is ok to share a /home always suggest using a different user name. Then none of the data is shared, but you share the partition. I find it better to create a data partition and use that in every install. I prefer using links but others also suggest bind may be better way to mount the folders in your shared data partition in each /home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be some problems with dotfiles (files that start with dots and are normally hidden), but no, there shouldn't be any new file that you need to create for Ubuntu to work normally.